# Filtering out a return character added by textarea

Tags: javascript, html, string

I ran across a bug in textarea, or in our parsing of it, that I am having an issue correcting.  We have a textarea box with a `maxlength` of 250.  However, if one enters a 250 character string, removes one character, then enters a newline, submits it, then opens it again to edit it, the length reads as zero (as it is now over the max length) and is flagged as invalid.  At first I thought it was our data storage, but when looking over the string that I get back from textarea, it has a bizarre newline character in it that has a length of 3.

The string
`asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf;laksdf;alsdfkasdl;fjasldfkja;sldfkja;sdlfkasdl;fasdl;fasdlf;kjasdf;lkajsfklas;fajs;fja;sdlfkjasd;flka↵sdf;laskdf;alsdfkjasldfkjas;dlfkas;ldfjkas;ldfkasl;dfjkasdl;fja;sld`

The character in question
`↵`

As character codes:
`97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,97,115,100,102,59,108,97,107,115,100,102,59,97,108,115,100,102,107,97,115,100,108,59,102,106,97,115,108,100,102,107,106,97,59,115,108,100,102,107,106,97,59,115,100,108,102,107,97,115,100,108,59,102,97,115,100,108,59,102,97,115,100,108,102,59,107,106,97,115,100,102,59,108,107,97,106,115,102,107,108,97,115,59,102,97,106,115,59,102,106,97,59,115,100,108,102,107,106,97,115,100,59,102,108,107,97,8629,115,100,102,59,108,97,115,107,100,102,59,97,108,115,100,102,107,106,97,115,108,100,102,107,106,97,115,59,100,108,102,107,97,115,59,108,100,102,106,107,97,115,59,108,100,102,107,97,115,108,59,100,102,106,107,97,115,100,108,59,102,106,97,59,115,108,100`

This means that the string I get from textarea has a length of 252 despite the length reading as 250 before being submitted.

The first question I have, is why is this happening?  I expected `\r\n` to be there, but instead I'm left with this odd character.

I have tried to filter it out using the following:

`description = description.replace('↵', '\n');`

`description = description.replace('\r\n', '\n');`

`description = description.replace('\x21B5', '\n');`

but it failed to replace the character.  I tried just getting the index but was unable to find the character despite copying it from the string that is being parsed.  So my second question is, how can I filter out this character?

Comment: Where/how are you viewing the string? Some IDEs and Debuggers choose to represent the newline character as ↵, which would explain why you're not able to programatically remove it because it's not technically in the string.

Comment: I tried chrome and Edge devtools, notepad++, visual studio, and I guess StackOverflow.  I also tried some other cases so I'll edit the question to reflect those.  Good note.

Comment: The HTTP spec stipulates that "hard" returns (places where the user actually hit the "Return" or "Enter" key to insert a line break) must be transmitted as a CR LF pair. In the past, and possibly still to this day, the `.value` property value of the corresponding DOM node *did not reflect that fact*.

Comment: Did you try doing `description.replace('\u21b5', '\n')`?

Comment: I tried filing browser bugs, and that was a frustrating though bleakly humorous exercise.

Comment: @Nathan Just tried it to no avail.

Comment: @Pointy But why is the length of the CR LF symbol reading as 3 characters and why can't I seem to find it via JS?

Comment: @SannahPotts: Why not just do substring and limit it to 250 characters? E.g. `description.substring(0, 250)`

Comment: What if you just trimmed the string to the first 250 characters then? `str.substr(0, 250)`

Comment: The reason I don't want to trim to 250 is that it would eliminate some customer input which is a jarring experience and it would never get past a code review.

Comment: @SusannahPotts How did you get the string you posted? Getting the text value of the element? Try looping through it and printing out the character codes for each character. See what character codes you get for that enter character.

Comment: Try `description = description.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");` though as I said you still may have server-side issues.

Comment: How does it eliminate customer input if the textarea is already limited to 250 characters?

Comment: @SusannahPotts if you prevent default, does it not prevent the enter character from being entered into the string? you could just write a handler to prevent default if the keycode was 13?

Comment: @KhauriMcClain If I'm typing out a list of items, and each return reads as 1 character in textarea, but consumes three when it gets submitted and parsed in javascript,then I just strip to 250 characters, I would lose a lot of potential text.

Comment: @SusannahPotts: Gotcha on the substring. Didn't see that the character is in the middle of the string. It seems that your best bet is to get the character codes by looping through the string and then replace using the character codes. If you have a jsfiddle or somewhere where we can see this issue I can send a solution.

Comment: @RachelGallen it seems likely that the textarea would not properly reflect the newline if she did a prevent default.

Comment: @Nathan yes indeed.. missed that

Comment: @SusannahPotts try this http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/jnad9e1u/

Comment: @SusannahPotts see this fiddle; it shows the difference between using .val and .serializeArray https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/106hsn2y/

Comment: Sorry, I had a meeting.  I am not actually doing any Javascript processing, just sending the value on its way via AngularJS and REST.

Comment: We have a length output via angular model binding where we are reading the length of the string from the object it is being binded to.

Comment: It calculates to the exact same length as the fiddle, which is also incorrect.

Comment: That is to say, once a form submits a textarea, it converts hard returns to /r/n or a similar character; per Pointy's earlier comment yet both the fiddle and my length are both treating the return as one character until a form submit.

Comment: @RachelGallen I think what you're misunderstanding is that the length we're calculating is just a display, it has nothing to do with the limitation of text input.  The textarea is calculating the text to be 250 when, on submitting, it shows it to be 252 in the JS.  I don't see why you had to come back with rudeness when you were the one not understanding.

Comment: @RachelGallen I did after you responded, I had only seen your other fiddle prior.  The reason it's irrelevant, however, is because the actual text limitation we're using is the `maxlength` html directive on the `textarea` element.  If our own text display is wrong, so be it, but we're not using that for anything functional.  If the text really is wrong, by which I mean is over 250 characters when I hit return, then textarea should be limiting me from going over 250 characters when I try to hit return.  As it stands, it is not, and the length I get from the string is 252. (continued...)

Comment: @RachelGallen The reason I know it's 252 is because if I paste it into the textarea again, the `maxlength` directive works and says it is too long to be valid.  So, how it's being calculated is technically irrelevant.  I'm more concerned with how to prevent the confirmed character growth.

Comment: @RachelGallen We're also not using JQuery...which is why it's not tagged anywhere.

Comment: @SusannahPotts To be clear, the length is only increasing by one, not two, for each newline according to this jsfiddle. This is from `\n` becoming `\r\n` according to the standard. The jsfiddle has two enters, thus two `\n`s becomes two `\r\n`s. The issue here is not with the submission but with when you reload the values into the textarea from what I gather. So why not simply replace `\r\n` with `\n` when reloading the form? Or replace `\r\n` with `\n` server-side as soon as it gets the submission so that you only deal with the extra characters when it's first transmitted at submission?

Comment: @Nathan I have tried that, unfortunately, even using character values, I cannot seem to remove the character because I cannot target it in the string.

Comment: @SusannahPotts you can target the string if you search for it by code; see https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/tryit.asp?deci=8629&ent=crarr for 3 codes that all display this symbol. In future, target it on entry, by handling it on keycode ==13 (replace the character with whatever you wish on entry and if necessary correct the count in js).. p.s. jquery is just fancied-up javascript; there's equivalent for pretty much everything

Comment: I've been trying to use those codes in my js to filter out the character but have had no luck.  Is `String.prototype.replace` sufficient or is there another function I should be using?

Comment: SusannahPotts, `String.prototype.replace` should be fine. Can you have a script log the character codes for the whole string when reloading to edit? (and also give us the sample text you used)

@RachelGallen Changing it on key entry won't help as it is entered in the textarea as `\n` but in accordance with the standard it is serialized as `\r\n`. Based on the feedback, she has not been able to replace the value even using the unicode values of the character enough.

Comment: @Nathan The sample string is in the OP, as well as the specific character. I updated the answer with the codes.

Comment: @RachelGallen 2 things, 1 `I've been trying to use those codes` verbatim from what I said to you. 2. Please leave.

Comment: At any rate, the answer for me ended up being `str.replace(String.fromCharCode(8629), '')`

Comment: @SusannahPotts I only saw your comments now as I logged off the site quite a while ago. How funny how the answer was in the link provided by me; the one that you said you'd been trying 'verbatim'..

Comment: Looks like you're measuring the string in *characters*, but then constrained by *bytes* after encoding to UTF-8.   The `↵` (Unicode 8629) requires 3 bytes to encode (`0xE2 0x86 0xB5`), hence the discrepancy.  What you need to do is measure the length of the UTF-8 encoded bytes, rather than the length of the character string.

Comment: @RachelGallen And yet even I was wrong when posting that, I had thought I filtered out that character but I was wrong.  It ended up being character code `10`.  How many times are you going to come back when you say you don't have interest in this question?